# gridview hyperlinkfield url path issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

lets say i have the following link `stackoverflow.com` stored in db.

When i click the link from grid-view it redirect me to below path

```
http://localhost:30987/Main/stackoverflow.com
```

Note I am taking user input so i cant add http:// to user input because i cant determine the user website use HTTP or HTTPS

How can i solve this issue ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Website" SortExpression="Website">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" Text='<%# Bind("Websitelink") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Websitelink") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Impossible with `HyperLink`. But try [HtmlAnchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead

Comment: same issue occurred with HtmlAnchor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502526/is-there-a-way-to-assign-an-external-url-to-a-hyperlink-without-appending-http

Answer (score 0):

As like Andrei mentioned in the comment, use HtmlAnchor(`<a>`) instead for `<asp:HyperLink` to make it work. You code will looks like the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Website" SortExpression="Website">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="<%#Eval("Websitelink") %>"><%#Eval("Websitelink") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```